# Data format: Gnuplot and output from Fortran

Tags: fortran, gnuplot

So, I've been working on some simulations and I got a problem with data format.
The data file I want to plot is composed of 3 columns of data: X Y f(X,Y). In Fortran I use the following command

```
26  format(2F11.3,ES16.5)    
write(2,26) X(i),Y(j),prob(i,j)
```

to generate a file like this:

```
   -490.001   -490.001     2.21004E-99
   -490.001   -485.001     4.65201E-98
   -490.001   -480.001     9.49095E-97
```

Then, using the command below in gnuplot 5.0

```
reset
set terminal gif animate size 800,600 enhanced font 'Helvetica,10'
set size square
unset cbtics
s=201
set palette rgb 34,35,36; 
set pm3d map
set dgrid3d 201,201
set output "novo12.gif"
do for [i=0:0]{
set autoscale fix
splot 'rtp.txt' u 1:2:3 every :::(0+i*s)::(s+i*s) notitle 
}
set output
```

I get [image: this image]. Which is wrong and seems to have no physical meaning. However, when I give up using the format statement in Fortran and write the file with

```
write(2,*) X(i),Y(j),prob(i,j)
```

I get a data file like:

```
  -490.000809582900       -490.000809582900       2.210036061559572E-099
  -490.000809582900       -485.000801321850       4.652007002167014E-098
  -490.000809582900       -480.000793060800       9.490949372368304E-097
```

Then, with the same gnuplot command I get [image: this image], which is correct!

I could go with the list-directed output since it works, however there is another file with a vector field written in 4 columns (X Y dx dy) and using the free format to write the data will result that the 4th column won't fit in the same line as the first 3, making it 'unreadable' by gnuplot.

Why isn't gnuplot understanding the data? How do I fix this?

Comment: As you're getting very small numbers like `2.21004E-99` can you check whether you get an even smaller one like `9.18491-100`?  Alternatively, if that's a problem, try changing that last format thing to `ES16.5E3`.

Comment: Yes there are values lower than 1E-100. Thank you very much for your help! That totally did it! I'm new to this site so I don't know if there is a way to label this post as [solved] or something like that. Anyway, would mind to explain why that worked? What does  ".5E3" mean?

Comment: This is likely unrelated to your question, but note that if your data is already in grid format you probably don't want to use `dgrid3d` (and maybe not even `pm3d`), because the colors in your image will not correspond directly to the data in your file. Consider `plot ... with image` instead.

Comment: Hi, @user8153. Thank you for your reply! I did what you said, removed dgrid3d/pm3d map and used: plot/splot ... with image. And in both cases I got an error message from gnuplot saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and no image was produced. What am I doing wrong? Also if I maintain pm3d map without using dgrid3d, the result is just a black image.

Comment: are those tiny numbers actually significant to your plot?

Comment: The fact that you are getting a "Segmentation fault" shows that something  _very_ strange is going on. Can you post (or link to) your datafile? What is the precise version number of gnuplot you are using?

Comment: Here is the text file for the picture I posted: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QnEcJnyKqbL3rmGGQ0VTfsjNjZf83Yai/view?usp=sharing

And about gnuplot, in the terminal it says "Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    last modified 2016-02-21". Thanks for the help, again.

Comment: I suggest asking about this in a different Gnuplot-only question. It is very far from the original problem with the Fortran format.